# PHP Export Date range

Tags: php, sql, database

I have a working database export to xls but I need it to export a particular date range based on the 'closed' date. (See code below).

For example, I'd like it to export all 'closed' dates for last month and/or this month (Range: Sept 1, 2012 to Sept 30, 2012  or  Oct 1, 2012 to Oct 31, 2012)

```
<?PHP


//EDIT YOUR MySQL Connection Info:
$DB_Server = "localhost";        //your MySQL Server
$DB_Username = "root";                 //your MySQL User Name
$DB_Password = "";                //your MySQL Password
$DB_DBName = "ost_helpdesk";                //your MySQL Database Name
$DB_TBLName = "ost_ticket";                //your MySQL Table Name

//$DB_TBLName,  $DB_DBName, may also be commented out & passed to the browser
//as parameters in a query string, so that this code may be easily reused for
//any MySQL table or any MySQL database on your server

//DEFINE SQL QUERY:
//edit this to suit your needs
$sql = "Select ticketID, name, company, subject, closed from $DB_TBLName ORDER BY closed DESC";


//Optional: print out title to top of Excel or Word file with Timestamp
//for when file was generated:
//set $Use_Titel = 1 to generate title, 0 not to use title
$Use_Title = 1;
//define date for title: EDIT this to create the time-format you need
$now_date = DATE('m-d-Y');
//define title for .doc or .xls file: EDIT this if you want
$title = "MDT Database Dump For Table $DB_TBLName from Database $DB_DBName on $now_date";
/*

Leave the connection info below as it is:
just edit the above.

(Editing of code past this point recommended only for advanced users.)
*/
//create MySQL connection
$Connect = @MYSQL_CONNECT($DB_Server, $DB_Username, $DB_Password)
     or DIE("Couldn't connect to MySQL:<br>" . MYSQL_ERROR() . "<br>" . MYSQL_ERRNO());
//select database
$Db = @MYSQL_SELECT_DB($DB_DBName, $Connect)
     or DIE("Couldn't select database:<br>" . MYSQL_ERROR(). "<br>" . MYSQL_ERRNO());
//execute query
$result = @MYSQL_QUERY($sql,$Connect)
     or DIE("Couldn't execute query:<br>" . MYSQL_ERROR(). "<br>" . MYSQL_ERRNO());

//if this parameter is included ($w=1), file returned will be in word format ('.doc')
//if parameter is not included, file returned will be in excel format ('.xls')
IF (ISSET($w) && ($w==1))
{
     $file_type = "msword";
     $file_ending = "doc";
}ELSE {
     $file_type = "vnd.ms-excel";
     $file_ending = "xls";
}
//header info for browser: determines file type ('.doc' or '.xls')
HEADER("Content-Type: application/$file_type");
HEADER("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=MDT_DB_$now_date.$file_ending");
HEADER("Pragma: no-cache");
HEADER("Expires: 0");

/*    Start of Formatting for Word or Excel    */

IF (ISSET($w) && ($w==1)) //check for $w again
{
     /*    FORMATTING FOR WORD DOCUMENTS ('.doc')   */
     //create title with timestamp:
     IF ($Use_Title == 1)
     {
         ECHO("$title\n\n");
     }
     //define separator (defines columns in excel & tabs in word)
     $sep = "\n"; //new line character

     WHILE($row = MYSQL_FETCH_ROW($result))
     {
         //set_time_limit(60); // HaRa
         $schema_insert = "";
         FOR($j=0; $j<mysql_num_fields($result);$j++)
         {
         //define field names
         $field_name = MYSQL_FIELD_NAME($result,$j);
         //will show name of fields
         $schema_insert .= "$field_name:\t";
             IF(!ISSET($row[$j])) {
                 $schema_insert .= "NULL".$sep;
                 }
             ELSEIF ($row[$j] != "") {
                 $schema_insert .= "$row[$j]".$sep;
                 }
             ELSE {
                 $schema_insert .= "".$sep;
                 }
         }
         $schema_insert = STR_REPLACE($sep."$", "", $schema_insert);
         $schema_insert .= "\t";
         PRINT(TRIM($schema_insert));
         //end of each mysql row
         //creates line to separate data from each MySQL table row
         PRINT "\n----------------------------------------------------\n";
     }
}ELSE{
     /*    FORMATTING FOR EXCEL DOCUMENTS ('.xls')   */
     //create title with timestamp:
     IF ($Use_Title == 1)
     {
         ECHO("$title\n");
     }
     //define separator (defines columns in excel & tabs in word)
     $sep = "\t"; //tabbed character

     //start of printing column names as names of MySQL fields
     FOR ($i = 0; $i < MYSQL_NUM_FIELDS($result); $i++)
     {
         ECHO MYSQL_FIELD_NAME($result,$i) . "\t";
     }
     PRINT("\n");
     //end of printing column names

     //start while loop to get data
     WHILE($row = MYSQL_FETCH_ROW($result))
     {
         //set_time_limit(60); // HaRa
         $schema_insert = "";
         FOR($j=0; $j<mysql_num_fields($result);$j++)
         {
             IF(!ISSET($row[$j]))
                 $schema_insert .= "NULL".$sep;
             ELSEIF ($row[$j] != "")
                 $schema_insert .= "$row[$j]".$sep;
             ELSE
                 $schema_insert .= "".$sep;
         }
         $schema_insert = STR_REPLACE($sep."$", "", $schema_insert);
         //this corrects output in excel when table fields contain \n or \r
         //these two characters are now replaced with a space
         $schema_insert = PREG_REPLACE("/\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r/", " ", $schema_insert);
         $schema_insert .= "\t";
         PRINT(TRIM($schema_insert));
         PRINT "\n";

     }
}

?>
```

Comment: So are you looking to export the tickets for a month? If so you can just extract the month from the date_closed field.

Comment: So add a WHERE clause to your SQL query

Answer (score 1):

Just add a WHERE clause to your SQL query.  For example, assuming `closed` is a datetime or timestamp field:

```
Select ticketID, name, company, subject, closed from $DB_TBLName
WHERE closed BETWEEN '2012-09-01 00:00:00' AND '2012-09-30 23:59:59'
ORDER BY closed DESC
```

you need to make sure you have an index on `closed` field as well for best performance.

Comment: Is there a specific argument to export all tickets for last month or for this month only?